# How to serialize a Mtom SOAP message in WCF

Tags: c#, .net, linq, wcf

Based on the following SOAP XML message how can serialize this xml to serialize and extract all elements within the ReviewCallbackMessage into a single XElement? The SOAP Message coming in is using MTom encoding. I hope someone can shed some light on this. It seems like a flaw within WCF, but maybe it's something w/ my contract settings.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:oasis:names:tc:legalxml:wsdl:WebServicesProfile-Definitions-4.0">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
        <NotifyCompleteRequestMessage xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:legalxml:wsdl:WebServicesProfile-Definitions-4.0">
<SendingMDELocationID xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:legalxml:schema:xsd:CommonTypes-4.0">
    <IdentificationID xmlns="http://niem.gov/niem/niem-core/2.0"></IdentificationID>
</SendingMDELocationID>
            <SendingMDEProfileCode xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:legalxml:schema:xsd:CommonTypes-4.0">urn:oasis:names:tc:legalxml:schema:xsd:WebServicesMessaging-2.0</SendingMDEProfileCode>
            <ReviewCallbackMessage xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:legalxml-courtfiling:schema:xsd:ReviewFilingCallbackMessage-4.0" xmlns:nc="http://niem.gov/niem/niem-core/2.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                <nc:DocumentFiledDate>
                    <nc:DateTime>2018-06-07T13:55:56.0Z</nc:DateTime>
                </nc:DocumentFiledDate>
            </ReviewCallbackMessage>
        </NotifyCompleteRequestMessage>         
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

This is the contract method and serializing class I'm using. In reality this should load the complete body into the attribute, but it's only loading the first node SendingMDELocationID. There has to be a way to load the complete xml body into one attribute without serializing the whole xml body since if I remove the SendingMDELocationID and SendingMDEProfileCode from the envelope it gives me exactly what I need which is the ReviewCallbackMessage node + all of it's descendants.

```
public NotifyCompleteResponse NotifyReviewComplete(NotifyCompleteRequest request)

[System.ServiceModel.MessageContractAttribute(IsWrapped = false)]
public partial class NotifyCompleteRequest  
{
    [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace = "urn:oasis:names:tc:legalxml:wsdl:WebServicesProfile-Definitions-4.0", Order = 0)]
    public XElement NotifyFilingReviewCompleteRequestMessage;

    public NotifyFilingReviewCompleteRequest()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post a valid XML request? Why is the `<nc:DocumentFiledDate>` element broken? Where is the `nc` namespace defined?

Comment: Sorry actually, I had to reduce the size of the xml envelope down since it had confidential information I couldn't post and forgot to add the namespace. I have updated the namespace above. Hopefully you can help me resolve this problem.